# CodeIgniter Phil Sturgeon's REST_Controller in PHP 5.6.28 authentication failed

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, authentication

I have used Phil Sturgeon's `REST_Controller` both in CodeIgniter 2 and 3, and all succeeded, both in localhost and hosting which various version of PHP.

Now, I have problem in 1 hosting which use PHP 5.6.28, the problem is authentication failed, and it shows message not authorized.

Thank you for all help and suggestion

Comment: You'll need to give more information than this, this could be anything. Are there any errors in your logs, what is happening, what is actual output...

Comment: Also you can post issues on the GitHub repository, which receives regular features, updates and bugfixes from the chap who's been maintaining this library. It's not mine anymore! https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver